# Integer value of NSPopUpButton Selected Item

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to convert a string value of a selected item in a NSPopUpButton to it's int value by doing this (the items in the popup are a variety of numbers):

```
txtUPs = [txtUPs stringByAppendingString:btnUPs.titleOfSelectedItem];
numUPs = (int) txtUPs;
NSLog(@"%i" ,numUPs);
```

Instead of getting the integer 6 (when I select 6 from the popup) I get a huge number like 26376. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: The expression `(int) txtUPs` is a "type cast" expression. You are telling the compiler to simply behave as though `txtUPs` were an `int`. It doesn't convert or interpret or anything like that. `txtUPs` is not a string. It's a variable holding a **pointer** to a string object. That is, it holds an address in memory. Addresses are in fact numbers. So, you are telling the compiler to treat the address held in `txtUPs` as though it were an `int` and assign that value to `numUPs`. That's why you get some arbitrary value. That's the address held by `txtUPs`.

Comment: Thanks all. I understand Ken's point about txtUPs being a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [number formatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html) for this. It will handle the transformation in a localized way. (The string is presented to the user, so should be localizable.)

```
NSString *stringValue = [txtUPs stringByAppendingString:btnUPs.titleOfSelectedItem];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter =[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

// Configure the formatter, if you need to
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle
…

// Convert it
NSNumber *numberValue = [formatter numberFromString:stringValue];
int value = [numberValue intValue];
```

BTW: The approach to get the internal program value from the displayed value might break: Think of items like "> 1000" or value representations that cannot be converted by a number formatter, i. e. "10k5".

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string to its integer value, use the integerValue string method. For example:

```
NSInteger selectedNumber = [btnUPs.titleOfSelectedValue integerValue];
```

Comment: Either use `NSInteger` or `-unsignedIntegerValue`. Don't mix `NSUInteger` with `-integerValue`.

Comment: Beside this the string comes from the UI and should be localizable. `-integerValue` does not do this job.